# Use serializable during taking data from api via ktor

Tags: android, json, kotlin, serialization, ktor

I have problem which taking data from api. because my serializable is different then data classes and I don't know method which I can make it correctly.

How can I take data from this Json data. I try to take this from api via ktor, but I have problem during taking. Json file which I try to take look like this.

```
[
  {
    "email": "email@test.pl",
    "id": 123,
    "user_name": "userName"
  },
  {
    "email": "email2@test.pl",
    "id": 1233,
    "user_name": "userName2"
  }
]
```

I try using serializer and look like this.

```
@Serializable
data class Users(
    val userList: List<Department>
)


@Serializable
data class User(
    val email: String,
    val id: Int,
    @SerialName("user_name")
    val userName: String
)
```

I taking data using ktor.

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json(
            Json {
                useArrayPolymorphism = true
            }
        )
    }
}
```

and method which get look like this.

```
try {
    val response: Users = client.get{
        url(url)
    }.body()

    Log.d("getDataFromUrl", "${response.userList}")
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d("getDataFromUrl", "${e.message}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code. The two changes might help you to resolve it.

1. Change the Departments to User data class in your Users data class

From :

```
@Serializable
data class Users(
      val userList: List<Department>
)
```

To :

```
@Serializable
data class Users(
      val userList: List<User>
)
```

1. As your json array does not contains a key I think thats the reason the Serialization failed to Parse the json. So please change your code like below

```
    try {
        val response: Users = client.get{
            url(url)
        }.body<List<User>>()
    
        Log.d("getDataFromUrl", "${response.userList}")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("getDataFromUrl", "${e.message}")
    }
```